# Fetch data from 20 related tables (through id), combine them to a json File and leverage spring batch for this

Tags: sql-server, json, join, spring-batch, apache-kafka

I have a Person database in SQL Server with tables like address, license, relatives etc. about 20 of them. All the tables have id parameter that is unique per person. There are millions of records in these tables. I need to combine theses records of the person using their common id parameter, and convert to a json table file with some column name changes. This json file then gets pushed to kafka through a producer. If I can get the example with the kafka producer as item writer- fine, but real problem is understanding the strategy and specifics on how to utilize **spring batch** item reader, processor, and item writer to create the composite json file. This is my first Spring batch application so I am relatively new to this.

I am hoping for the suggestions on the implementation strategy using a composite reader or processor to use person id as the cursor, and  query each table using the id for each table , convert the resulting records to json and aggregate it to a composite, relational json file with root table PersonData that feeds to kafka cluster.

Basically I have one data source, same database for the reader. I plan to use Person table to fetch id and other records unique for the person, and use id as the where clause for 19 other tables. convert each resultset from the table to json, and composite the json object at the end and write to kafka.

Comment: did you try your options? what is your specific question?

Comment: I guess stored procedure options seems to be discouraged, and huge join query option is also out so I have edited my question, and the specific question is how to create composite item reader that queries all tables and builds a complex json file out of it for PersonData

Answer (score 0):

We had such an requirement in a project and solved it with the following approach.

1. In Splitflow, that run parallel, we had a step for ever table that loaded the data of the table in the file, sorted by common id (this is optional, but it is easier for testing, if you have the data in files).
2. Then we implemented our own "MergeReader".
   This mergereader had FlatFileItemReaders for every file/table (let's call them dataReaders). All these FlatFileItemReaders were wrapped with a SingleItemPeekableItemReader.
   The logic for the read method of the MergeReader is as follows:

   ```
   public MyContainerPerId read() {

      // you need a container to store the items, that belong together
      MyContainerPerId container = new MyContainerPerId();

      //  peek through all "dataReaders" to find the lowest actual key
      int lowestId = searchLowestKey();

      for (Reader dataReader : dataReaders) {
          // I assume, that more than one entry in a table can belong to
          // the same person id
          wihile (dataReader.peek().getId() == lowestId) {
          {
                container.add(dataReader.read());
          }
      }

      // the container contains all entries from all tables
      // belonging to the same person id    
      return container;
   }
   ```

If you need restart capability, you have implement ItemStream in a way, that it keeps track of the current readposition for every dataReader.

Answer (score 0):

I used the **Driving Query Based ItemReaders** usage pattern described  [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html) to solve this issue.

Reader: just a default implementation of JdbcCursoritemReader with sql to fetch
        the unique relational id (e.g. select id from person -)

Processor: Uses this long id as the input and a dao implemented by me using 
          jdbcTemplate from spring fetches data through queries against each of 
          the table for a specific id (e.g. select * from license where id=) and map results in  list format to a POJO
          of Person - then convert to json object (using Jackson) and then to 
          string

Writer: either write the file out with json string or publish json string to a 
        topic in case of kafka use

Answer (score 0):

We went through similar exercise migrating 100mn + rows from multiple tables as a form of JSON so that we can post it to a message bus.

The idea is create a view, de-normalize the data and read from that view using JdbcPagingItemReader.Reading from one source has less overhead.

When you de-normalize the data make sure you do not get multiple rows for master table.

Example - SQL server -

```
create or alter view viewName as
select master.col1 , master.col2,
(select dep1.col1,
               dep1.col2
               from dependent1 dep1
        where dep1.col3 = master.col3 for json path
       )                as dep1
from master master;
```

The above will give you dependent table data in a json String with one row for each master table data. Once you retrieve the data you can use GSON or Jackson to convert it as POJO.

We tried to avoid JdbcCursoritemReader as it will pull all data in memory and read one by one from it. It does not support pagination.